# No Manifest Attribute in android studio 2.3 for AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

I recently downloaded Android studio 2.3 but the feature to create `AndroidManifest.xml` which could be found in 2.2 is not in the latest version(2.3) I downloaded.
  Is there any plugin to add that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your project's manifest file explicitly

Go to project's root, right click, and over the contextual menu, select: New/Other/Android Manifest File